# The "free" command does not display the correct values

Tags: linux, rhel, process, memory, top

We have a very strange issue on one of our machine redhat 7.2.

How it can be free - 0 , while used is 43 from total 47?

```
[root@master ~]# free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             47          43           0           0           3           3
Swap:             7           5           1
[root@master ~]# free -k
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       49552508    45570336      296216      237396     3685956     3510224
Swap:       8093692     6053196     2040496
```

From `top`:

```
top - 17:34:40 up 10:39,  2 users,  load average: 0.77, 0.81, 0.83
Tasks: 789 total,   1 running, 788 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.7 us,  0.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.7 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 49552508 total,   831304 free, 45669236 used,  3051968 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8093692 total,  2056872 free,  6036820 used.  3412568 avail Mem
```

Comment: `3685956 buff/cache`, combined with rounding errors make the last 4G be 'not free', but not used, either. https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: A quick read of [the manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html) should clarify why this isn’t amazing.

Comment: There is a detailed explanation on how ram is consumed and reported by free on https://www.linuxatemyram.com/ sometimes what we call free to be consumed linux calls it used but available to be consumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong column. In the first output, the free memory i.e. the RAM available for new applications  (without any swap usage) is shown in the `available` column.  This correctly reports 3 Gb, or 3510224 Kb.

47 Gb - 43 Gb = (with rounding errors) 3 Gb

[Linux borrows any unused memory for disk caching](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/), that's why you see zero in the `free`column. But the memory allocated for disk caching is released as soon as other applications request it.